# Running functions simultaneously from an akka actor

Tags: scala, akka, actor

From an actor (akka.actor.Actor) how can I execute a method twice simultaneously? Try to do it with Futures, but if the future does not respond, the actor does not take more requests ...

Comment: How about to actually include some piece of code in your question that represents your current issue?

Comment: "if the future does not respond, the actor does not take more requests" - that doesn't seem right, i.e. that's not the case if you use Futures in the intended way. Could you post the code in question?

Comment: Sorry.. I assumed it was very simple. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, actors should not block. Dealing with actors, you should think in dataflow manner. Draw a dataflow diagram like this:

```
          --> methodCall1 --> |----------|
 actor1 /                     |  actor2  |  
        \ --> methodCall2 --> |__________|
```

Actor2 can be inplemented as an Akka actor, which counts incoming messages and reacts when both messages has arrived. In this case, `methodCall1` and `methodCall` must know actor2 and send messages to it.

Or actor2 can be a CompletableFuture which is derived from the future of one of method calls using method `thenCombine`.